# Running UI From WCF Hosted Inside WindowService

Tags: wcf, windows-services, usersession

I have a Window Service thats hosts wcf:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (serviceHost != null)
    {
        serviceHost.Close();
    }
    serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof('myservicetype'));
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint
            (typeof('myservicetype'),
            binding, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myconfig"]
            );
        serviceHost.Open();
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

the wcf listen to requests, one of the request is to open notepad on the server,
this doesnt work because the service is running on session 0(no gui...),
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can open notepad regardless of what you're using (windows app, service etc) if the identity associated with the service got enough permissions.
You can then use `Process.Start("notepad.exe", yourTextFile);`

Or just `Process.Start(yourTextFile);` if notepad is the default program for handling text files.

Comment: will not work- the notepad wont show, you can see it the task manager

Comment: continuing my last edit... it will show in taskmanager but you wont see it visualy

Comment: @user1763180 have a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx